# FDT 5 Max Milestone 8 / Debug Connection from iOS Device

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, debugging, connection, fdt

What is the current workflow for receiving debug traces from an iOS device within the FDT console?

How do you customize the ADT args?

*

*${package} ${target} ${connection} ${sampler} ${market} ${special} ${legacyaot} ${signing} ${provision} ${output} ${content} ${icons} ${platformsdk}**

I tried to replace **${connection}** with **-connect MY_IP_ADDRESS**, but that does not do the trick, the debugger dialog window does not pop up. Is an ANT-script still the only solution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found it – even if you create an ad-hoc development .ipa file, you have to replace the **${target}** with **-target ipa-debug**.

I still don't receive debug traces after starting the fdt debugger and then starting the app on the device. Any tipps are welcome.

WIFI is enabled, USB cable is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so easy – while focussing on the '**deploy**' on device tab I totally missed the new part of FDT 5 Max in the **debug configuration** for the main class.